# How do you access the artwork from an MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm writing an app using Xamarin and have an `MPMediaItem` that I obtained using the `MPMediaItemPickerController`.

While I can access the text values using `MPMediaItem.valueForProperty`, when I pass `MPMediaItem.ArtworkProperty` to get the artwork, it seems to return a `MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork`.

Casting the return value to a `MPMediaItemArtwork` results in a `null` and there doesn't appear to be a corresponding class for `MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork` in the Xamarin IOS API.

Is this an omission or is there another way that I should be accessing the artwork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After play about a bit more it turns out a hard cast works just fine (as opposed to using an `as`), like this:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork artwork = (MPMediaItemArtwork)mediaItem.ValueForKey(MPMediaItem.ArtworkProperty);
```

Once you have the `MPMediaItemArtwork` you can get the raw image data like this:

```
UIImage image = artwork.ImageWithSize(artwork.Bounds.Size);
NSMutableData jpegData = image.AsJPEG() as NSMutableData;
```